# Class 'mysqli_connect' not found

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

Okay so this is my problem now. I am using PHP 5.5.12 and MySQL 5.6.17. The php mysqli_connect is checked on my php settings but still getting error. ANy help? Thanks in advance.

Here is my dbcon.php

```
<?php
//Connect to the database 
$link = new mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "towertec_master"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}?>
```

And this is my main.php

```
<?php
include ("lib\dbcon.php");

// is a client logged in?
include("lib/login_check.php");

include("lib/fetch_org_data.php");
$thispage="main";   
?>
```

This is the error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in C:\wamp\www\Trading\lib\dbcon.php on line 3
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0014  244472  {main}( )   ..\main.php:0
2   0.0023  247912  include( 'C:\wamp\www\Trading\lib\dbcon.php' )  ..\main.php:2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/mysqli_connect) is a function, not a class. What you want is either:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(...);
```

or

```
$link = new mysqli(...);
```

Both are equivalent.

Comment: I don't know if Id say the are equivalent one returns an object the other a resource, but I suppose that is splitting hairs.  Personally I only use PDO now, lol,  I +1'd you though, cheers.

Comment: Big thanks. Now I got rid of that error. (Now I am back on index.php and could not login. ) Thanks again.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix The documentation (as well as my experimentation) says they both return objects.

Answer (score 2):

You should do :

```
$link = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "towertec_master");
// without new
```