# wamp / php error Fatal error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in C:\wamp\www\finalproject\Connections\Main_DB.php on line 9

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp

hi could someone assist me in this issue.

this is my connection string:

```
<?php

    #FileName = "Connection_php_mysql.htm"
    #Type = "MYSQL"
    #HTTP = "true"

    $hostname_Main_DB = "localhost";
    $database_Main_DB = "mydb";
    $username_Main_DB = "root";
    $password_Main_DB = "";

    $con = new mysqli_connect($hostname_Main_DB,$username_Main_DB. $password_Main_DB, $database_Main_DB) or die ( "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno());     $db=mysqli_select_db($database_Main_DB,$con) or die( "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .     mysqli_connect_errno());
?>
```

I have installed `wamp` server and `mysqli` extension is enabled.

hope you will be able to help me with this issue,

Tnx, Yotam

Comment: Change `.` to `,` in your `mysqli_connect()` does that do the trick?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26725174/2460773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code should be

```
<?php

    #FileName = "Connection_php_mysql.htm"
    #Type = "MYSQL"
    #HTTP = "true"

    $hostname_Main_DB = "localhost";
    $database_Main_DB = "mydb";
    $username_Main_DB = "root";
    $password_Main_DB = "";

    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname_Main_DB,$username_Main_DB,$password_Main_DB, $database_Main_DB) or die ( "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno());

    $db=mysqli_select_db($database_Main_DB,$con) or die( "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_errno());
?>
```

You should remove "new". For more information read **[this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

**Edit :-**

Also you have added `.` in between two variable that should be `,`

`$username_Main_DB. $password_Main_DB` replace this with `$username_Main_DB,$password_Main_DB`

Comment: that worked but i'm getting a diffrenet error :
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @Yotam707 you have put . in between variable replace dot with comma. I have updated  my answer

Comment: I noticed it and changed it, still getting the error mentioned above

Comment: @Yotam707 getting error which one ?

Comment: i'm sorry you were right, it's working. sorry for the confusion and thank you for your replay :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$con = mysqli_connect(..);
```

Remove the new keyword.