# php user registration can't connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, user-accounts, user-registration

I am having problems getting my PHP to connect to my database. This is my first time ever working with PHP and I am not sure what is wrong, I have searched all over the internet without finding a solution. Hopefully you guys can help!

Here's the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in D:\wamp64\www\einsteindesigns\reg.php on line 4

and the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pwd = "";
$db = "userdb";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
if(! $mysqli )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']) {

        $first = $_POST['first'];
        $last = $_POST['last'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $confirmpassword = md5($_POST['confirmpassword']);

            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

               $sql = "INSERT INTO $db (first, last, email, password) "
                      . "VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$password')";

                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration Successful";

                }
                else {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Error: User account could not be 
created. Please try again.";
                }
                mysqli_close($mysqli);          
            }
    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords do not match";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get precisely when trying to establish connection

Comment: You know you need to fill in the details on lines 3-6 ($host, $user, $pwd & $db) with the info you set when you installed/configured your MySQL database?

Comment: If you have errors disabled so add these lines at the beginning of your script as : `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Unfortunately, there are quite a many errors in the code right now. There's no [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) which would actually execute the `INSERT` query. The `else` which says _Passwords do not match_ is not where it'd correspond to the `if` that checks the two passwords.

Comment: Have you started the MySQL Server? Which Collective Package you are using??? XAMPP,WAMP,MAMP etc???

Comment: @PhpDev This is the error message that I am getting. Fatal error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in D:\wamp64\www\einsteindesigns\reg.php on line 4

Comment: @SLWS Im am using WAMP, so my host is "localhost", user is "root", i don't have a password, and my database is called "userdb".

Comment: @DhruvSaxena So you're saying I need to move the else stating Passwords do not match right below the if that checks the passwords, and I need to add a mysqli_query just above the $sql insert, right?

Comment: Line 4 doesn't have `mysqli_connect`.. You also are open to SQL injections once this is working... assuming `$sql` is ever going to be executed

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai I have started the MySQL Server and I am using WAMP.

Comment: Install XAMPP instead WAMP is not really much better choice..has always issues...!

Comment: @Ophillion Well, to me there's an `if` that is missing. After `$sql = "INSERT INTO....`, you'd want to run the query using `mysqli_query()` and then maybe check for the errors using an `if` and when there are none it'd continue to _Registration Successful_. And if there are some errors (in which case it'd fall through to `else`), the code block under `else` which says _User account could not be 
created_ would then make sense with that missing `if`, thereby also putting the second `else` for _Passwords do not match_ in the right place.

Comment: Also your error doesn't seem to me to be from this code as on line 4 your `mysqli_connect` is not there so fetch the correct code and post it here without any modifications..! also do not write as `mysqli_connect ();` remove the space between the brackets `()` and the `mysqli_connect` so your error will be fixed then..! :D

Comment: Take a look at this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776955/wamp-php-error-fatal-error-class-mysqli-connect-not-found-in-c-wamp-www-fi

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman Thank you! I'm new to php and had no idea these were such security risks. Would something like this be better?                          
    $first = trim($_POST['first']);
    $first = strip_tags($first);
    $first = htmlspecialchars($first);

Comment: @Ophillion No, use parameterized queries.